# How to add custom domain inside office add-In Manifest file after publishing to store?

Tags: office365, manifest, office-addins, word-addins, web-app-manifest

Is there any possibility to add a custom domain after publishing Manifest file to app store? I have a requirement, in which I have to add a new AppDomain in manifest file after publishing it to App Store.

For e.g My Manifest file contain following AppDomains

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://login.windows.net</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

After publish it, I want to add one more domain e.g https://login.customdomain.com

Is it possible to add custom domains dynamically like:

```
<AppDomain>https://login.customdomain.com</AppDomain>
```

Any help on this will be appreciate!

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear:  are you talking about **dynamic** domain names (e.g., ones you can't know about in advance), or just about adding a particular item to the static list of the already-submitted manifest?